# Windows 10, сборка завершает работу сразу после запуска

Tags: c#, wpf

Сборка работает нормально на Win 7 - 8.1, но вот на win 10 запустил и только через пойманное исключение выяснил суть ошибки, и написало мне вот такое вот:

"Предпринята попытка загрузить сборку из сетевого ресурса, что в предыдущих версиях .NET Framework могло привести к помещению сборки в "песочницу". Этот выпуск .NET Framework не включает политику CAS по умолчанию, поэтому данная загрузка может быть опасной. Если эта нагрузка не предназначена для изоляции сборки, включите переключатель loadFromRemoteSources. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569."

Как решить? Читал что нужно установить `loadFromRemoteSources = true`, но файла `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` у меня нету, что мне делать что бы этой ошибки не было на Windows 10?

Comment: эммм..так вам наверное не devenv.exe.config надо править (его и правда скорее всего не существует), а конфиг вашего приложения

Comment: А какой код вылетает? Какое приложение вы запускаете?

Comment: Разобрался, оказывается в Win10 появилась какая то фича новая, которая заблокировала все `dll` которые у меня вместе с `exe` и что бы нормально работало нужно отключить эту блокировку для каждой `dll`. Вот такие вот нововведения windows...

Answer (score 1):

Долго мучался чтобы побороть такое поведение, и не заставлять клиентов каждый раз снимать галки с dll. Одно из решений: не отдавать пользователям готовый конфиг файл, а генерить его при первом запуске приложения. Тогда он создается уже без признака небезопасного. Например так:

```
static void Main()
    {
        if (!(File.Exists(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName + ".config")))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName + ".config", Properties.Resources.App);
            Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

В конфиг файле при этом должна быть разрешена загрузка из удаленных источников:

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Гм, но ведь не из-под админа не получится записать файл в папку с приложением?

Comment: Получится, если приложение лежит в папке текущего пользователя, или любой другой с доступом на запись у него.

Answer (score 0):

Такое новшество появилось ещё в 7-ке а может и раньше. При скачивании или распаковке средствами проводника ОС помечает такие ехе и dll файлы как неблагонадежные и при попытке запуска либо блокирует запуск с вопросом что делать либо срубается с нехваткой прав.

Comment: Ну а как решить такую проблему, что бы мою программу не блокировало? Пока что единственное что я смог придумать - это сделать установщик, который тоже скачивается заблокированным но вроде устанавливается нормально...